# AWS User vs Resource Permissions

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, permissions

When a user has Resource-based permissions to a ressource but does not have User-based permissions  for that service. Can he use that service than?

example : user Jack has Resource based permission to use the S3 bucket 'jamm'. But Jack has no permission to use S3. Can Jack use the S3 bucket?

Comment: How are you defining the resource based permissions? And how are you prohibiting Jack from using S3?

Comment: the resource based permissions : In your S3 bucket -> properties -> permissions-> add jack to grantees

User base : just give jack no permission, he won't have it..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't have permissions to access the S3 service, then you cannot use it at all.

In order to access any S3 bucket, you must have permissions to execute the S3 commands such as `s3:GetObject`. These permissions tells AWS which commands the user is allowed to execute. Anything not explicitly allowed is automatically denied.

The S3 bucket policy (your resource-level permissions) instruct the S3 service which users are allowed to access the bucket. But that only happens **after** the user has been given the needed permissions to execute S3 commands with which to access the bucket.

So you need:

1. Give the user permissions to execute the S3 commands to access the bucket (default is none), and
2. Give the bucket a policy to restrict the users that can access the bucket (default is anyone in the AWS account)

It is possible to restrict some S3 commands to your bucket, so the user has permission to execute `s3:GetObject` (for example), but only on your bucket.

But some commands, such as `s3:ListAllMyBuckets` cannot be restricted this way.